# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found - JAVA MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

Why I am getting double slash at WEB-INF/view//admin. I am new at Java MVC so please any suggestion, what am I doing wrong?

here is my code `

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>`
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping
```

Controller -

```
@Controller
    public class ControllerClass {
@RequestMapping(value = "/deck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView viewDeckPage(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
            System.out.println("in get method..");
            
                return new ModelAndView("/admin/deck");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 slashes because first one is coming from the view resolver which is `/WEB-INF/view/` and the second one you are returning as view name which is `/admin/deck` (slash before admin).

To resolve this you have to return only view name without a prefixed slash i.e `admin/deck`

Comment: I did remove slash from admin/deck. and double slash problem solved .It's request is getting to method and printing "in get method.." but on browser its still giving HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.

Comment: Ok..Is deck.jsp located inside admin folder in WEB-INF? Please give the location of the page

Comment: yes it's like WEB-INF/view/admin/deck.jsp

Comment: That's right, but if it is printing the statement and unable to find the page then the error should be unable to resolve view name but not 404 actually.

Comment: I can not understand where I am going wrong. It gives 404 with "Message: /Mercy/WEB-INF/view/admin/deck.jsp "

Comment: Hello. The next problem is solved now, thanks for your support. This worked for me : Right click on project-> properties->Deployment Assembly ->> add->> add your view folder then ->>apply and close.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash so your prefix is /WEB-INF/view